# AJAX post datastring getting cut off

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to post an email address using ajax to php and every time I send the email address variable gets cut off, so it is sent to the php as 'someone@gmail.c' for example. I have tried doing toString and escape but nothing seems to work.

Thanks.

```
 function postEmail(){

     var checkEmail = "someone@gmail.com";
     var dataString = 'checkEmail1='+ checkEmail;

     // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "myfile.php",
     data: dataString,
     cache: false,
     success: function(result){

     alert(result);
     } 
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Shortly after posting this, after trying for ages, I got it working.

I used encodeURIComponent and didn't even need to decode it the other end:

```
 var checkEmail = "someone@gmail.com";
 checkEmail = encodeURIComponent(checkEmail); //added this in
 var dataString = 'checkEmail1='+ checkEmail;
```

Comment: Cool, helped me even years later ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the recommended way to build your jQuery AJAX request data:

```
var dataString = {checkEmail1: checkEmail};
```

See the examples in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

It is especially useful when you are posting multiple values, such as this:

```
var data = {
    something1 : yourVariable1,
    something2 : yourVariable2,
    something3 : 'hardcodedvalue'
}
```

I much prefer this over doing manual string concatenation and individual encoding of the data like you are doing.

Comment: I used encodeURIComponent shortly after posting this and it worked fine. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: See update.  This is the way jQuery recommends doing it and is a much cleaner solution.  Let jQuery do the data string assembly and encoding for you.